# A word for one who loves only one girl throughout his life

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, vocabulary

Just like one wife man is called : monogamous.

Is there any word for one who loves just one girl throughout his life time. For him one life, one girl matters.

History has seen such people. Are such people's action(of loving just one)  also described in words ?

Comment: Are you talking about John who loves Jane and only Jane and thinks that he should not love other girls or the belief in being in a loving relationship with one woman at a time OR the belief that if one is in a relationship than one should not sought out another relationship even if his partner died/left him/broke up etc?

Comment: Despite the recognized difference between love and marriage, 'monogamy' is still the most understandable word for this (people will understand what you meant). But if you insist on marriage not being involved (e.g. a man who may have been married many times, but kept a single mistress for all that time), then the best I can consider would be 'faithful', "The man was married three times, but he was emotionally faithful to his mistress the entire time".

Comment: On reflection, that sounds crazy. Really, 'monogamous' is the only word that really fits here.

Comment: Apart from solving crossword puzzles, why in the world would you need a **single word** (which nobody will have ever heard of anyway) instead of a richer yet simpler and clearer multiword expression?

Comment: @Mitch: "monogamy" is used for animals too, so I think that also fits for unmarried humans.

Comment: A [poet](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/178713).

Comment: why not get used to the idea that there's not a single word for every possible concept? Makes things much easier...

Comment: A [liar](http://xkcd.com/17/)? :)

Comment: A [fool](http://xkcd.com/458/)?

Comment: "We were high school sweethearts" is the only thing I've heard that's close.

Comment: Monogamy is opposed to polygamy, and has zero to do with the idea of romantic love being asked about here. Marriage and love do not always coincide.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might say "one woman man", meaning for that particular man, there was only one woman.  Usage:  He was a one woman man, and after his wife died, he never remarried.

Equally you could say, "one man woman", meaning for that particular woman, there was only one man.  Usage:  She was a one man woman who remained single after her love married another.

In "one woman man", the phrase "one woman" acts as an adjective to describe the man.

In English I am unaware of a single word to convey the meaning you require, other than monogamous.

Additionally, in English, monogamous is not gender specific.  A woman can be equally as monogamous as a man. Usage:  Both Bill and Mary were monogamous.  Luckily they were married to each other.

Comment: That won’t work without hyphens.

Comment: Monogamous does not convey the meaning required by OP - Monogamy is one man/woman **at a time** vs. **throughout his life time** in the question.

Comment: +1 It's not one word but it does convey the meaning and it's understandable.

Comment: @Honza That is not true. _Monogamous_ also means ‘forming only one relationship in a lifetime’, which is as close as you can get to the desired meaning.

Comment: @HonzaZidek curiously, there is a (rather odd and uncommon) word for that: [digamy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/digamy).

Comment: It would be good to have a phrase that didn't involve "man" or "woman" though. For example, is a "one man man" a gay man who is eternally devoted to a single man? Or his a "one man man" a man who isn't devoted to anyone but himself?

Comment: @corsiKa Apart from not necessarily being gay, isn't the latter just a subtype of the former?

Comment: In this context, "love" is meant to be an intimate, generally sexual, relationship. If a "one man man" is intended to not be a selfish person, he would by definition be a gay man.

Comment: Monogamous is a sociological term and opposed to polygamous. It is little to do with the notion here of romantic love as a lifetime "achievement".

Answer (score 13):

I would use "eternally devoted" or "devotes his/her life to his/her wife/husband/woman/man". I know these are not one words but they are the most pithy way I could think of to describe what you're describing.

Answer (score 6):

If it was me trying to describe someone like this, I'd refer somehow to an animal that is well known for monogamy.

> “They showed Swan-like dedication to each other.”
>
> “She's a real Turtle-Dove.”
>
> “He's an old Albatross.”

None of these are particularly good, but you could choose any one of the animals that mates for life, and create a term around it that's highly unique and relevant to your context.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't it be called "Faithful"?

I mean, monogamy does not imply any emotion, it simply restricts whose name appears on your family card at any given time.

Faithful means one stays loyal to their companion

[Free Dictionary entry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/faithful)

[Merriam-Webster entry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faithful)

Whether this lasts for a lifetime or lean enough to allow for another companion to fill in should the current one passes away is something I don't know of. But this is the word that comes to mind when emotion is involved

Comment: One can remain faithful in the absence of love

Comment: But can one be in love in the absence of faith?

Comment: @Philip good statement, and I agree with corsiKa: one won't fall in love in the first place without faith. But I have to agree that the word focuses on loyalty instead of emotion. I simply remember that this word carries more emotional weight compared to, say, "monogamous" which is more administrative in nature

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there is a consensus that a single-word solution is not as easy as it sounds. I tried to find ones that would be close fits, but maybe these examples can lead to a hybrid that does take care of your needs.

*Soulmate* seems like it would be a close single-word solution. However, I don't believe it guarantees love.

**Soulmate:**

> a person ideally suited to another as a close friend or romantic
>   partner.

Another generic one I came up with is *love-locked*. It's not the most beautiful hyphenated combo, but it definitely portrays the fact you are locked into love with the person. Again, this one's concern is it doesn't guarantee your love is only for one person.

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects in which *monogamous* isn't exactly right:

1. Monogamy is explicitly about spouses or at least partners, not about the first and last love of your life who maybe doesn't know about her luck yet, or worse, isn't as thrilled as she should be.
2. Even serial monogamy is monogamy in the proper sense of the word.

If 1 is not a problem, I would suggest *perpetually monogamous*.

I think what makes this problem tricky is that one actually has to be in that situation to consider it worth describing by a single word. The world around this person is much more prosaic, and unfortunately this often includes the target of the affection. (A good description of that state in general can be found in *De l'amour*, *On Love*, by the French writer [Stendhal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stendhal).)

A pure description with probably all the necessary connotations is *romantic first-time lover*. But I am afraid this has also some connotations that will make most romantic first-time lovers reject it: *first time* sounds as if there could be a second time, which is objectively true in practically all cases, but of course subjectively totally wrong; and *romantic* relativises the feelings by pigeonholing them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use 'undying love'.

Maybe someone can make something from Amaranthine ==>> [amaranthine - definition, etymology and usage, examples and related words](http://www.finedictionary.com/amaranthine.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about 'life monogamist'? ('life-monogamist' maybe?)
Or, if you wish to explicitly include informal relations: (life) monoamorist/-amorous, monoromantic (by analogy with 'polyamorous' & words for so-called romantic orientations). However, none of these seems to be widely used. Oh, and they are of course more general than your question, so might have to use 'life monogamous man', or even 'life monogynous man'.

Animals of such behaviour are apparently called 'mating for life', and 'monogamy for life' has some results in Google. Also, less scientifically, some of the following combinations appear:
[life/lifetime/lifelong] [mate/companion/partner] or '... for life', although probably in the context "he is her life mate", not "he is a life mate".

Answer (score 0):

After all answers given to this question, I have reached on one that is

> Loyal

Answer (score 0):

You might call him or her a *true-lover*.  (**Not** a *true lover*.)  Yes, I imagine that this was coined just now - no idea whether anyone else has ever used it or ever will.  But I'll bet that it will be understood.

But no -- it does not imply **single** love, but rather someone who believes in *true love*.

Closer to what you are asking would be *single-lover* (also probably not a known word, but also probably understandable). Again, the hyphen is significant here: this is someone who is and has been *single-loving* (loving only one person), not a lover who is single.

And if your question is indeed limited to loving only one **girl** then you could stretch it to *one-girl-lover*. (Of course, during the lover's lifetime the one girl  presumably ceases to be a girl at some point... ;-))

Answer (score -3):

[Monandry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monandry) = a marriage form or custom in which a woman has **only one husband** at a time 
[Polygyny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamy) = When a man is married to more than one wife at a time.

while, [Monogamy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogamy) is the state or practice of being married to only one person for lifetime or at a time. (**Having only one wife**)

Thus, someone who loves or have only one wife can be called : "Monogamous"

Comment: You are not answering the question! Notice **at a time** in your definitions vs. **throughout his life time** in the question.

Comment: I do. Please take a while to read the whole wikipedia defintion : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogamy

Comment: Also, love and marriage need not co-exist together. The asker wants a word that denotes love. Marriage doesn't necessarily denotes the existence of love. Marriage to one could be a belief system or ritual, and love is certainly not in such an equation.

Comment: Well, the Wikipedia entry is interesting: "Marital monogamy may be further distinguished between: marriage once in a lifetime, ..." You should have cited *this*.

Comment: I think what @HonzaZidek is saying is that, monogamy is one wife at a time while the asker might be asking, loving only one and not re marrying therefore, whether the man is monogamous is irrelevant. He could have multiple wives yet only loved one woman in his lifetime :) Again, love and marriage is a fine line.

Comment: Why love and marriage needn't co-exist ? The most important condition before signing a marriage is the Love Confessions between the individuals, then the approvment of marriage.

Comment: Well, there are many countries where marriage can be bought/given as parents wish, whether from diplomatic reasons or just money/tradition. Anyway, monogamy cannot answer this question because, John can marry Jane and then get divorced and marry Kate next, he would still be monogamous but it doesn't denote that he loved only one woman in his lifetime. In this case, he would have loved multiple woman, assuming love is the reason for the marriage. Oh, and in the question, the asker doesn't want the word "Monogamous" apparently so you are really not answering the question.